# React performance - anonymous functions and memoizing via useCallback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to understand the trade-offs of having anonymous functions as well as whether `useCallback` hook actually brings any benefit for my use cases.

Let's take the following function component:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';

function Example() {

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

 const onClickCount = useCallback(() => {
    setCount(count + 1)
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClickCount}>
        Click
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Does having `useCallback` make sense if the function is going to update every time `count` is incremented? Does it actually impact performance positively/negatively, as I know memoizing also does not come for free?  What's the performance difference if I were to simply change `onClick` to `onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}`?

What if we change the scenario a little:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';

const data = [
   {id: "1", text: "Foo"},
   {id: "2", text: "Bar"}
]

function Example() {

  const [lastSelected, setLastSelected] = useState(undefined);

 const onClickUpdate = useCallback((id) => {
    setLastSelected(id)
  }, [lastSelected]);

  return (
    <div>
       {data.map((e) => 
         (<button onClick={() => onClickUpdate(e.id)}>
           {e.text}
         </button>)
       }
       Last selected: {lastSelected}
    </div>
  );
}
```

For the scenario above, I cannot avoid having an anonymous function (I guess?) as I need to pass the object id. So this would create a new function on every rerender. Is that bad? Does it have worse performance than the first snippet above?

Comment: in your first example you can pass a callback to `setCount` which will avoid having to ever update the memoized function. `setCount(count => count + 1);` so you could pass an empty dependency array. But in the second example you're already declaring a new anonymous function in the button element every render anyway and for this simple case could avoid declaring the handler at all `onClick={() =>  setLastSelected(e.id)}`

Comment: Memoizing is mostly about being able to prevent large chunks of the tree from having to re-render (which means you need to have some `memo()` component somewhere). The functions passed to `useCallback` are *always* re-created on every render, the memoization is about whether this new function is returned by `useCallback` or whether we keep the one from the previous render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's understand the purpose of `useCallback` hook. It is used to memoize a function and prevent unnecessary re-rendering of the child components that depend on it. In your first example, since the `onClickCount` function is dependent on the count state, using `useCallback` hook makes sense. However, since the function is being updated every time count is incremented, the memoization may not provide any significant performance benefits.

As for the performance difference between `onClickCount` and `onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}`, the former will create a new function instance every time the component re-renders, whereas the latter will create a new function instance every time the button is clicked. So in terms of performance, the latter may be slightly better since it won't create unnecessary function instances on re-renders.

In your second example, using an anonymous function to pass the object id is unavoidable. However, it will create a new function instance every time the component re-renders, which may impact performance if there are many buttons or if the component re-renders frequently. In this case, using useCallback hook to memoize the function may provide performance benefits.

So in short, whether to use `useCallback` hook or not depends on the specific use case and the performance impact of memoization. But in general, using anonymous functions may impact performance, but it may not be significant in simple scenarios.